# Akka - How to retrieve a reference to the child actor of an entity in a shard region?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Say I have an entity that holds a reference to its child actor as one of its fields. I would like to be able to pass that child reference to a sender that was asking for it:

```
class SomeActor extends FSM[State, Data] {
  when(Idle) {
      case Event(GetChild, _) =>
          val child = context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])
          sender() ! child
          stay.using(/*save state here*/)
```

The request for the reference goes to the shard region:

```
val getChildFuture = someRegion ? Message(id, GetChild)
val child: ActorRef = Await.result(getChildFuture, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[ActorRef]
// do something with the actor ref here
```

When I tried this, I would get a report saying that the message/response from the child actor was not delivered to the dead letters.

The reason I wanted to get the child reference was that I wanted to turn it into a sink (i.e. send a stream to it), and I didn't want to keep sending the bytes to the shard region and have it forward them to the `SomeActor` entity (I'm under the impression this is costly, and you can correct me on this).

Am I even doing things correctly? I'm also open to alternative approaches.